HTTP name resolution for local HP printer
OS is Windows 11
My local HP printer has a web server at http://HPF38629 (That's listed in the printer's network configuration as the printer hostname). This works, I can connect to the printer by pointing my browser to the given URL. I can also ping HPF38629 with no problems
However, nslookup goes to the DNS server and comes back with "non-existent domain". HPF38629 is not listed in the local hosts file. So my question is, how is this name being resolved?

It's hard to understand what problem you are trying to solve, or are you just trying to learn?

I just wanted to understand how a strange local name got resolved.  The first place I looked was the local hosts file but that was not modified so it became a research project and I learned about two previously unknown protocols. A commenter on ServerFault (where I originally posted this) mentioned mDNS but was incorrect about the real solution.

OK a little work with Wireshark and I have an answer. The name is not resolved by mDNS, it is resolved by LLMNR (Link Local Multicast Name Resolution). mDNS only resolves names in the .local domain.
Windows does send mDNS requests for HPF38629.local but that fails to get a response. It sends that request for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. The query fails because the printer does not recognize the .local domain.
Then it sends two LLMNR requests (IPV4, IPV6) for the basename HPF38629 and gets both IPv4 and IPv6 responses from the printer.
LLMNR was defined in RFC 4795 but was never adopted as a standard.
Microsoft has depricated LLMNR but it stil works and the HP printer is depending on it. Look for interesting complaints if it ever really goes away.
Another interesting discovery: LLMNR resolved names are not stored in the Windows DNS cache.
